# Depth first search on Neo4j with filtering on node properties

Tags: filter, neo4j, properties, depth-first-search, neo4j-apoc

I would like to perform a depth first search on my graph and so, get all the paths existing from a given node ('N1456' in my example), and all the nodes of theses path must have the same property "PROPERTY_TO_FILTER".
Typically, my graph is composed of two types of node, and two types of relations.
For now, I tested the following request :

```
WITH "
MATCH (my_node{name : 'N1456'})
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(protein, {uniqueness:'NODE_GLOBAL', bfs : FALSE}) YIELD path
WITH path, my_node, last(nodes(path)) as subgraph
WHERE my_node<> subgraph and my_node.my_property CONTAINS 'PROPERTY_TO_FILTER'
RETURN nodes(path), length(path) AS len
ORDER BY len DESC" AS query
CALL apoc.export.json.query(query, "my_results.json", {})
YIELD properties, data
RETURN properties, data;
```

However, the results are not the ones attended. I get a list of paths but only the first node has the property "PROPERTY_TO_FILTER" ; this filter is not taken into account for the other nodes...

I guess I should put a filter at apoc.path.expandConfig level, but I see in the documentation that this is only possible to filter the node label, not the node properties.

Could someone help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

```
MATCH(fromNode:LABEL{name : 'N1456'})-[r:REL_TO_TRAVERSE*1..2]->(toNode:LABEL)
WHERE toNode.my_property CONTAINS 'PROPERTY_TO_FILTER'
RETURN fromNode,r,toNode
```

It's called variable length pattern matching:
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/patterns/#cypher-pattern-varlength

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm not sure this solution is doing what I actually need. I'm looking for a way to perform a DFS, extraction all the paths possible according to the conditions given on my node properties. It seems to work on my first node, but after that, the filter doesn't seem to work on the other nodes